# Bootstrap @media print responsive-table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have some @media print for printing my page content, but i have problem with boostrap class **.responsive-table**, when I try to ptint my page table cut offs?

I there some solution fro printing responsive tables in bootstrap
Here is my css for now

```
@media print {  
#top-navigation{
display:none !important;
}
footer{
display:none !important;
}
.main-footer-sub{
display:none !important;
}
a[href]:after {
content: none !important;
}

.hotel-detail-sidebar{
display: none !important;
}

#menu-navigation{
display:none !important;
}
#carousel{
display:none !important;
}
#preporuka-agencije{
display:none !important;
}
#preporuka-agencije{
display:none !important;
}
#offers-sugessted{
display:none !important;
}
#share-buttons{
display:none !important;
}
.tab-content > .tab-pane {
    display: block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
}
.responsive-tabs{
display:none !important;}

.sattravel-kontakt{
display:none !important;}
.table-responsive{
overflow:visible !important;
}
 *,
  *:before,enter code here
  *:after {
    color: #000 !important;
    text-shadow: none !important;
    background: transparent !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
            box-shadow: none !important;
  }
  a,
  a:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
  a[href]:after {
    content: " (" attr(href) ")";
  }
  abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
  }
  a[href^="#"]:after,
  a[href^="javascript:"]:after {
    content: "";
  }
  pre,
  blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;

    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  thead {
    display: table-header-group;
  }
  tr,
  img {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
  }
  p,
  h2,
  h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
  }
  h2,
  h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
  }
  select {
    background: #fff !important;
  }
  .navbar {
    display: none;
  }
  .btn > .caret,
  .dropup > .btn > .caret {
    border-top-color: #000 !important;
  }
  .label {
    border: 1px solid #000;
  }
  .table {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
  }
  .table td,
  .table th {
    background-color: #fff !important;
  }
  .table-bordered th,
  .table-bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #ddd !important;
  }
    .container {
    width:100% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://blog.donnierayjones.com/2014/10/fix-bootstrap3-printing/

Answer (score 0):

> My best solution

just wrap the main `table` with outer `table.tabel-responsive`

**HTML**

```html
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <!-- TABLE TO PRINT -->
            <table id="attendance_table"  class="table table-bordered  bg-warning-o-10">
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```css
@media print {
    body * {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    #attendance_table, #attendance_table * {
      visibility: visible;
    }
    #attendance_table {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
    }
  }
```